# Is it a good practice to use float to position element?

Tags: css

Can I use float to place the element in a webpage rather than using position: absolute or relative?

Comment: Well, it has its own purpose. The answer is yes but it depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally? Sure, that's what it's there for.

Whether it's the right choice depends on what exactly you want to do.

You just need to take care of the consequences - for example, the need for using the `clear` property when using multiple subsequent floated elements to avoid undesired effects.

Answer (score 4):

As many other HTML and CSS features, the `float` property has been terribly abused. It was designed to deal with little floating elements (such as pictures in a paragraph) and it's used to create the page layout. The problem is CSS does not really provide us with better alternatives. So IMHO it isn't good practice but it's normally the way to go :)

BTW, ten years ago browsers used to have a very poor support for the `position` property (esp. Internet Explorer) so it was often not an option. For instance, you could not create rounded corners by placing relative boxes in the corners of the main box: they were always displaced. Luckily, this has improved a lot and nowadays is an excellent tool.

Answer (score 2):

Floats are an excellent way to position elements on your page, sometimes essential in fact.

Answer (score 0):

When using float,  a box is first laid out according to the normal flow, then taken out of the flow and shifted to the left or right as far as possible.Whereas in position a box is removed from the normal flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings) and assigned a position with respect to a containing block.So both has it own uses, and you can use them according to your need at the particular place.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use float ... rather than using position: absolute or relative?

No. Float has limitations compared to absolute or relative positioning. Not every layout which is made by relative or absolute positioning can be made by using Float. But that statement goes vice versa.

And as all answers have stated yet: each has its own purpose, limitations and usage.